# How can I request a URL with ".." in it using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am building a personal website with flask. In order to test it, I want to request `localhost/foo/../bar`.  However, when I navigate to this URL firefox automatically rewrites it and requests `localhost/bar` instead. This occurs even if I use the network tool to edit and replay a request.

My code is supposed to specifically reject paths including `..`, because they can lead to directory traversal attacks. However, I need to test my code by sending such "bad" requests.

How can I request a URL with a `/../` segment using Firefox?

Comment: What kind of crazy setup do you have? Did you setup whatever code you have in `localhost/foo/` to somehow respond to a path that is `../bar/`? Meaning the path in the application is `bar/`? The reality is Firefox — and most all browsers — are properly converting `localhost/foo/../bar` to `localhost/bar` My advice to you is your application is badly engineered; a URL in the browser is not the same as a path in the file system.

Comment: My code is supposed to specifically reject paths including "..", because they can lead to directory traversal attacks.  However, I need to test my code by sending such "bad" requests.

Comment: Aaaah! That makes sense. Will post an answer shortly after you see this comment.

Comment: If this protection is in your backend (server side) code, then you can simply insert it in the right place while debugging.  You could try s0omething like owasp

Answer (score 4):

Building off of [Giacomo1968's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1759921/167207), you can use curl you do this.  However, you need to add `--path-as-is` to prevent it from resolving `/../`s.

```
curl -ILk --path-as-is localhost/foo/../bar
```

See Giacomo1968's answer for additional useful information.

Comment: Nice! Never knew abhor `--path-as-is` before.

Answer (score 3):

### Don’t rely on GUI web browsers to debug server behavior.

#### GUI web browsers are optimized to display content and cache content for speedy retrieval; not necessarily to debug fundamental web server-based behavior.

Well, Firefox is a GUI (aka: human friendly) browser and if you want to test this you are better off just using Curl from the terminal for a header request to test how the application will behave. Run this Curl command and look at the header output:

```
curl -ILk http://localhost/foo/../bar
```

Also, while I think it is good to have URL access hardened against directory traversal in the application, this stuff is typically handled by the web server that is reverse proxying the whole application.

Check out [this blog post](https://medium.com/appsflyerengineering/nginx-may-be-protecting-your-applications-from-traversal-attacks-without-you-even-knowing-b08f882fd43d): It explains how `merge_slashes` works in Nginx (the web server most often using with Python and Ruby apps) to better understand that, without you even knowing it, Nginx defaults to `merge_slashes on` meaning that there is utterly no way do any directory traversal.

Comment: Unfortunately while curl does not merge repeated slashes (`localhost/foo///bar` is unchanged) it does resolve `/../`s.  Using a python socket I see that your command sends an http request starting with `HEAD /bar HTTP/1.1 ...`.

Comment: Addendum: wget behaves the same way.